# Help me understand these memory statistics from Process Explorer

Tags: windows, memory-management, process-explorer

I'm trying to do a very rough measurement of the amount of memory my large financial calculation requires in order to run. Its a very simple command line tool which prices up a large number of financial instruments and then prints out a result.

I decided to use Process Explorer to view the memory requirements of the program. Can somebody kindly explain the difference between the two fields labeled a and b in the screenshot:

I currently believe that:

The value labeled "a" (Peak Private Bytes) is the largest amount of memory (both actual physical memory and virtual memory on disk) which was allocated to the process at any instantaneous moment.

The value labeled "b" (Peal Working Set) is the largest amount of physical memory allocated at any instant during the life of the process.

[image]

Comment: As for the working set, not quite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780836(WS.10).aspx):

> The **working set** is the set of memory pages that were touched recently by the threads in the process. If free memory in the computer is above a threshold, pages are left in the working set of a process, even if they are not in use. When free memory falls below a threshold, pages are trimmed from working sets. If the pages are needed, they will be soft-faulted back into the working set before leaving main memory.
>
> [**Private bytes** are] bytes, that this process has allocated that cannot be shared with other processes.

What "peak" means in that context should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Random thoughts from observations and what the display of Process explorer says.
Working set is in Physical Memory section of the display so anyone saying it is virtual memory is confused. And it changes by odd numbers as RAM usage would normally change so it looks like working set is physical memory.
Private Bytes on the other hand is listed as Virtual memory. And watching it change seems to change is multiples of 16K, as Virtual memory normally changes as it swaps out pages of memory and not just random bits. For some reason I thought this should be 64 k pages but depends on the machine and version of Windows I suppose.